# Fetch certain values from dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have below dictionary. I need to drop `OS::<name>` from this dictionary (In this case first 3 key,value pairs). I am only interested in the rest of the key,value pairs. How can I achieve this? It would help if I can get the logic to be as short as possible.

```
{u'OS::project_id': u'xyz', 
u'OS::stack_id': u'xyz', 
u'OS::stack_name': u'XYZ', 
u'image': u'RHEL-7.2', 
u'private_network_id': u'xyz', 
u'floating_ip': u'xyz', 
u'volume_type': u'ceph_fake', 
u'volume_size': u'10', 
u'key': u'my_key', 
u'flavor': u'm1.small'}
```

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it. Note that dictionaries are unordered; they don't have a "first" key.

Comment: Dict comprehension? It seems pretty simple. Where are you stuck? Or did you not try anything?

Comment: `{key: value for key, value in d.items()  if not key.startswith('OS::')}`

Comment: Thanks, that gives me what I need

Comment: I thought this was read by you guys https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice

Comment: If you are wondering about the downvotes, they are most likely because of the total lack of research effort displayed on your part. This question has been asked a thousand times before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `dict comprehension`.

```
{key: value for key, value in d.iteritems()  if not key.startswith('OS::')}

{u'flavor': u'm1.small',
 u'floating_ip': u'xyz',
 u'image': u'RHEL-7.2',
 u'key': u'my_key',
 u'private_network_id': u'xyz',
 u'volume_size': u'10',
 u'volume_type': u'ceph_fake'}
```

Comment: why negative votes?

Comment: I got my answer, not sure about the neg votes though. Voted up. Thanks @VishnuUpadhyay

Comment: @VishnuUpadhyay: Because you have answered the question they indented to. In python 3 `d.items()` will do the same trick.

Comment: @Rahul there is no tag of python3 that's why i prefer python2.7.

Comment: Oh. I didn't see it.